# How does paraminterceptor converts from String to integer by itself?

Tags: java, struts2

How does  paraminterceptor sets the value for our action,how does it gets to know whether it is int,char,string or any other in our class? As we don't have to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

Introspection via reflection.

All parameters are strings. The parameter name is used to figure out what type the action property is. There is a set of default convertors that go from `String` to several default types.

You can also register custom type convertors to cover more action property types.